# What is the reasoning behind the recurrence relationship in the coin change problem?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, dynamic-programming, probability

I know how to use the recurrence relation in the coin change problem(total number of ways to obtain a sum S from a given set of coins), however, I do not understand where it comes from. I searched it on the internet and as far as I remember they throw up this fact( recurrence r/ship) and then they proceed on implementing it. Can someone explain it?

10{1,2,3,4} = 10{1,2,3} + 6{1,2,3,4}

The above equation is just an example. In words it means the total number of way to make 10 using the coins {1,2,3,4} is equal to the total number of ways to make 10 using {1,2,3} puls total number of ways to make 6 using the coins{1,2,3,4}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to count the possibilities to get the sum, you should consider the possibilities where you *don't* use a certain coin, and where you *do* use it (at least once). When you know the number of possibilities for the first case, and for the second case, then you know the answer: it is the sum of those two.

So, now the question becomes, how can I count the number of possibilities in these two distinct cases?

In the first case, you simplify the problem, because you exclude a coin type, bringing down the number of different kind of coins you can still choose from.

In the second case, you reduce the remaining amount to cover, since you have taken the coin. This is also reducing the problem: not in terms of available coins, but in the amount to sum up to.

In either case you can apply the same algorithm to the reduced problem. That is where recursion comes in: those reduced problems will again split into a case where you use a coin or not, ...etc.

Eventually the problem will be so much reduced that you can easily know the count of possibilities for it:

- If the remaining amount is zero: that is exactly what we aimed for: consider the coin selections that led to this point as a valid possibility, and return 1.
- if the remaining amount is negative, then you've apparently used too big a coin, and you should not count this as valid: return 0 as count of possibilities.
- If the remaining amount is strictly positive, **and** there are no coins left: apparently we discarded the last remaining kind of coin. This is not good. We cannot count this as a possibility, so return 0

These counts (0 or 1) will bubble up the recursion tree where you will add them together. That sum will on its turn also return further up the recursion tree, until eventually all possibilities have been added up.

Comment: I didn't know it's that easy, but only after you broke it down. Self-teaching isn't simple.